# switch an Android library to application (& back n forth) easily

Tags: android

Im using Android studio and gradle. I have 1 main app and 1 module. The module is used by the main app (as a library). At the same it can be a separate application - which can be done by changing "apply plugin: 'com.android.library' " to "apply plugin: 'com.android.application'" in its gradle file and some other parts (like the manifest, etc).

Is there a way to quickly switch from lib to app (back n forth) without doing the manual way? just asking

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper.  Create an app that just launches whatever you need to in your library, and use that when you want to use it as an application.

Comment: Yea. Im doing it now. But still hoping some other ways aside from the wrapper.

Comment: Why?  The wrapper does what you want-  it allows you to launch your library.  What advantages do you get by changing the other module constantly?  I don't see any, in fact I mostly see negatives.

Comment: i prefer not to create extra submodules/folder. =/

Comment: You'll spend a lot more time fighting the entire build system doing it your way rather than just doing it the way the system expects (that libraries are libraries and don't suddenly become applications).